# Generation of randomly looking graph coordinates

Tags: graph-theory, mg.metric-geometry, random-graphs

Let $G$ be some connected graph. We pick randomly $k$ distinct vertices $l_1, l_2, \cdots l_k \in V(G)$. We call them the landmarks.
We define $d(u,v)$ to be the length of the shortest path between the vertices $u,v$.
For each $v \in G$ we denote $coord(v) := \left(d(v,l_1), d(v,l_2), \dots ,d(v,l_k)\right)$, the graph coordinate of $v$.

For every two graph coordinates $A = (a_1, \dots, a_k), B = (b_1, \dots, b_k)$ we denote $mdist(A,B) := \max_i{|a_i - b_i|}$.
Note that $d(u,v) \geq mdist(coord(u), coord(v))$ for every two vertices $u,v \in V(G)$. This is true because of the triangle inequality.

For a given coordinate $A$, denote $approx(A)$ to be some coordinate $coord(v)$, $v \in V(G)$ that minimizes $mdist(coord(v), A)$.

Given the knowledge of $(coord(l_i) | 1 \leq i \leq k)$ (The coordinates of all the landmarks), I want an algorithm to generate random coordinate $X$ such that $approx(X)$ is close to uniform on $V(G)$.

**My previous attempts:**

- Trivial example: Picking $coord(l_i)$ where $i$ is chosen uniformly from the set $\{1, \dots ,k \}$. Every landmark $l_i$ is expected to be hit about $1/k$ times, while the other vertices are not hit at all. This is not very uniform on $V(G)$.
- Generating a random coordinate where every entry is chosen randomly as follows: $coord(l_i)_j$ where $i,j$ are both chosen uniformly from $\{1, \dots , k\}$. This did not give me good results.
- It can be seen that the set of legal coordinates (The kind of coordinates that satisfy the relevant triangle inequalities) is convex. This is because if $A$ and $B$ are legal coordinates, then $\alpha \cdot A + (1-\alpha) \cdot B$ is also a legal coordinate, for $0 \leq \alpha \leq 1$. I tried to generate a random coordinate of the form $\alpha_i \cdot coord(l_i)$, where $\alpha_i$-s are chosen randomly so that their sum is 1, and $\alpha_i \geq 0$. This did not give good results.

Comment: I don't understand the comment on the trivial example -- if every vertex is hit equally, how is that "not very uniform on V(G)"?

Comment: @Matt F.: The trivial example is uniform on the set of landmarks, but not on the set of all vertices of the graph.